# How to calculate the derating of one IC

Tags: motor, driver

We are using one motor driver IC which can provide max 2A. The motor driver IC part no is BD6222HFP-TR. Maximum current drawing for motor is 1.5A when it got stalled. We tried to calculate the derating for this IC, but we are getting different remarks. Can anyone please guide if this IC be used for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

You've identified the package as the high power one, so you have figures for the thermal conductivity junction to case, and you have a max junction temperature for the family.

Given your power supply voltage and motor current, and rDS on, you get dissipation. This dissipation multiplied by total thermal resistivity to ambient gives you the temperature rise.

Now you reach a point where they can't specify, because it's **your** heatsinking of the part that will control the case temperature and therefore the junction temperature. They give you some hints examples of 7cm2 of PCB an' all (note 5), but you may not be using that.

Comment: Thank you sir for your kind reply.Actually in this IC datasheet,it is given that power dissipation is 1.6w and Ron is 1 ohm.so power dissipation= square(I)*R.Here putting the value we will get the current is 1.26A.If as per the power dissipation maximum current drawn can be 1.2A how the maximum current of 2A as per the datashet be achieved.At 60C temp,can we be able to draw 1.5A current.

Comment: No time to study the data sheet now, but 1.6w is average dissipation. Is 2A non-continuous perhaps?

Comment: figure 29 shows output current versus voltage in the low state, at 2A it's about 0.8v, which is 1.6 watts for that output alone. Figure 23 supposely shows the high state output, but the current is only shown to 0.5A. However, the slope and resistance are similar, so it looks like you can expect 3.2 watts at 2A output, so you can't run at more than 50% duty cycle to not exceed power dissipation limits.

Answer (score 1):

As per automotive grade requirement maximum derating factor requirement is 0.6 and it should NOT exceeded after this.
In your case the

Derating factor is given by Operating current/ Rated current

Derating factor= 1.5A/2A
= 0.75